# Theme issues on app running on 4.4 devices

Tags: java, android, themes

So I was informed of an issue with an app we have.

Since updating a device to 4.4, the app loses all its text! It's almost as if it has gone 'invisible'.

In my manifest I have:

```
    <application
    .....
    .....
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

However, I've been informed this is perhaps not the best way of doing it?

My styles.xml is:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
</style>
```

However my style.xml inside values-v11 and values-v14 is:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="buttonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

I cannot figure out why this does not work on 4.4 devices, yet works fine on 4.3 and below.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found it was due to a bug within Android 4.4 and not displaying true type fonts correctly.

I changed all the fonts to OTF format and it started behaving as usual again!

I hear it is fixed in an internal tree but not released yet.